# Flutter video player not working when load video from file

Tags: ios, flutter, video, media-player

This is how i load the video from file

```
_videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath),
          videoPlayerOptions: VideoPlayerOptions(allowBackgroundPlayback: false))
print("----------Before----------$_videoPlayerController");
await _videoPlayerController.initialize();
print("----------After----------$_videoPlayerController");
```

> output in the console and it's stuck after printing before-- (Stuck whie initialize() call) there.

```
flutter: VIdoe :- /Users/KarmaLeen/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/
Devices/63291E82-251B-4895-A3C4-3895CB771306/data/Containers/
Data/Application/A8C19957-AA78-4A76-A7D2-2C10CE685D55/Library/
Application Support/Pesachim-41b-Rabbi-Sorscher-Chazara.mp4

flutter: ----------Before----------VideoPlayerController#aec48(VideoPlayerValue(duration: 0:00:00.000000, size: Size(0.0, 0.0), position: 0:00:00.000000, 
caption: Caption(number: 0, start: 0:00:00.000000, end: 0:00:00.000000, text: ), captionOffset: 0:00:00.000000, buffered: [], isInitialized: false, 
isPlaying: false, isLooping: false, isBuffering: false, volume: 1.0, 
playbackSpeed: 1.0, errorDescription: null))
```